# Move a div to specific spots on an svg path

Tags: svg

I have an SVG path that currently has an image travelling around it. I need to make it so that when you click on a button on the path, the image will travel to that specific spot?

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="route">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 1920" xml:space="preserve">
      <path class="cls-1" d="M288.56,7.45c1,1.17,13.77,15.18,14,16.67a8.66,8.66,0,0,1-.65,4.21,117.08,117.08,0,0,1-8.09,18.43c-.36.66-.82,1.39-1.56,1.55a2.71,2.71,0,0,1-1.88-.59L282.72,43a2.5,2.5,0,0,0-4.09.88C270.79,54.35,263,65.09,253.14,73.73c-3,2.61-6.16,5-8.71,8.06-.88,1-1.71,2.38-1.25,3.65a4.35,4.35,0,0,0,1.1,1.49,53.93,53.93,0,0,1,14.12,25.72,4.5,4.5,0,0,1,.12,2.12c-.59,2.2-3.69,2.33-5.41,3.84s-1.75,4.08-1.68,6.34a90,90,0,0,0,1.24,14.12c2,10.3,7.81,19.93,8.07,30.43-2.28,24.14-22.77,45.32-46.87,48.1-2.7.32-5.5.44-8,1.57a20.09,20.09,0,0,0-5,3.7c-32.78,29.91-57.73,67.22-82.35,104.13-2.88,4.32-5.79,8.7-7.48,13.61-2,5.91-2.2,12.26-2.35,18.5-.21,8.75-.38,17.73,2.58,26,3.67,10.22,11.8,18.29,15.91,28.34,4.49,10.93,3.91,23.44,8.47,34.35,1.61,3.85,3.84,7.44,5.16,11.4,2.32,6.94,1.68,14.52,3.28,21.65,2.18,9.7,8.12,20.64,3,29.16a373.16,373.16,0,0,0-36.31,54.7c-4.78,8.8-9.24,17.89-11.68,27.62-2.81,11.19-2.85,22.86-2.88,34.4,0,16.77,0,34,5.78,49.7,2.39,6.51,5.73,12.65,8,19.19,10.3,29.32-1.45,61.63,1,92.61.42,5.43,1.34,11,4,15.71,3.57,6.34,9.92,10.64,16.46,13.82,22.55,10.94,48.91,11,72.34,19.86,12.93,4.92,25.1,12.27,36.75,19.73,5.54-6.69,15.43-8.71,24.11-8.93s17.66.7,25.86-2.17a42.79,42.79,0,0,0,12.9-7.74c15.09-12.46,25-30,33.81-47.45,11.51-22.93,21.95-47.81,20.86-73.43-4.91-2.19-5.89-9.21-10.41-12.13-5.16-3.32-11.87-.21-18,0-7.93.27-15.06-4.5-21.47-9.19a604.83,604.83,0,0,1-70.37-60.38,24.51,24.51,0,0,1-5.05-6.35c-.8-1.66-1.24-3.5-2.27-5-2.1-3.15-6.11-4.31-9.77-5.27-35.8-9.32-70.81-22-104.91-36.35-4.52-7.11-4-16.94-4.71-25.34A85.91,85.91,0,0,0,99,520.19c-1.78-2.94-3.82-6-3.68-9.44a51.33,51.33,0,0,1,1-5.32c1-6.63-3.85-12.53-8-17.74-31.63-39.15-45.62-90.53-74.78-131.56a15.88,15.88,0,0,1-.82-14,14.43,14.43,0,0,1,10.56-8.1c2-.33,4.36-.43,5.38-2.16A5.54,5.54,0,0,0,28.8,328a120,120,0,0,0-3-11.95,21.64,21.64,0,0,0-2-4.93c-1.06-1.75-2.55-3.19-3.73-4.86a33.42,33.42,0,0,1-3.84-8.23c-3.28-9.13-6.58-18.33-8.06-27.92-1-6.17-1.14-12.44-2-18.62A86.93,86.93,0,0,0,.69,231a64.48,64.48,0,0,1,18.11-1.35c-14.94-40.19-3.59-88.94,27-119A156.85,156.85,0,0,1,64.48,95.09C80,83.88,96.75,74.38,113.42,64.9A46.07,46.07,0,0,1,124,60.05c5-1.35,10.31-.95,15.45-1.72C155.85,55.86,168,42.22,182.28,33.7c10.7-6.38,22.85-10,33.83-15.87,7.68-4.14,14.75-9.41,22.7-13s17.61-6.19,25.39-2.24c4.19,2.12,14.08-1.11,15-2.26"; />
      <circle id="one"       cx="295" cy="48"  r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" onclick="testFunc"/>
      <circle id="two"       cx="263" cy="65"  r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="three"     cx="258" cy="103" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="four"      cx="252" cy="135" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="five"      cx="131" cy="305" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="six"       cx="147" cy="502" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="seven"     cx="125" cy="538" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="eight"     cx="110" cy="563" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="nine"      cx="96"  cy="619" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="ten"       cx="110" cy="791" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="eleven"    cx="216" cy="841" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="twelve"    cx="287" cy="846" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="thirteen"  cx="323" cy="817" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="fourteen"  cx="349" cy="766" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="fifteen"   cx="355" cy="720" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="sixteen"   cx="320" cy="705" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="seventeen" cx="265" cy="660" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="eighteen"  cx="102" cy="528" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="nineteen"  cx="96"  cy="498" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="twenty"    cx="22"  cy="306" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="twentyone" cx="133" cy="59"  r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="twentytwo" cx="230" cy="8"   r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
    </svg>

    <div class="ship"></div>
  </div>
```

Each circle needs to have a click function and the ship needs to move to that circle from where ever it is currently positioned. I currently have basic animation of the ship moving around the svg path using css but understand I'll need to use javascript/jquery.

Comment: Please add an [mcve] and tell us what you have tried, and what you are stuck on.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question now :)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite easy to do.  The simplest way is with a javascript animation using `window.requestAnimationFrame()`.

See below.  I've documented what I'm doing, so hopefully it should be quite easy to follow.

A couple of notes:

1. I've only configured the pathOffsets for the first five circles. I've left the rest up to you.
2. This code assumes that you are going to display the SVG at 1:1 scale.  If you change that (ie. you change the SVG `width`), then the code will have to be modified, because otherwise the ship won't be positioned in the right place.

```js
const ship = document.querySelector(".ship");
const routePath = document.querySelector("svg .cls-1");

// The distance along the path that each circle lies
const pathOffsets = {
  "one": 45,
  "two": 90,
  "three": 141,
  "four": 176,
  "five": 407,
  "six": 0,
  "seven": 0,
  "eight": 0,
  "nine": 0,
  "ten": 0,
  "eleven": 0,
  "twelve": 0,
  "thirteen": 0,
  "fourteen": 0,
  "fifteen": 0,
  "sixteen": 0,
  "seventeen": 0,
  "eighteen": 0,
  "nineteen": 0,
  "twenty": 0,
  "twentyone": 0,
  "twentytwo": 0
}

const shipSpeed = 1;          // How far along the path to move for each animation step
var   currentShipOffset = 0;  // Where the ship is now
var   shipTarget = 0;         // The offset of where the ship is currently heading
var   shipMoving = false;

// Position the ship at a particular offset along the path
function setShipOffset(offset) {
  var pos = routePath.getPointAtLength(offset);
  ship.style.left = pos.x + 'px';
  ship.style.top = pos.y + 'px';
  currentShipOffset = offset;
}

// Start the ship moving to a particular circle
function startShipMovement(evt) {
  // Get the 'id' attribute of the circle we clicked on
  var circleId = evt.target.id;
  // Get the corresponding offset value
  shipTarget = pathOffsets[circleId];
  // If the ship isn't already moving, then begin the animation by requesting the first animation step
  if (!shipMoving) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(doShipStep);
    shipMoving = true;
  }
}


function doShipStep() {
  // If we are within one step of the target, then stop there.
  if (Math.abs(shipTarget - currentShipOffset) <= shipSpeed) {
    setShipOffset(shipTarget);
    shipMoving = false;
    return;
  }
  // Otherwise move one step in the correct direction
  if (shipTarget > currentShipOffset) {
    setShipOffset(currentShipOffset + shipSpeed);
  } else {
    setShipOffset(currentShipOffset - shipSpeed);
  }
  // and request another animation step
  window.requestAnimationFrame(doShipStep);
}



// Set the initial ship position to the start of the path
setShipOffset(0);
// If you want to set it to a particular "port", then you can use:
//setShipOffset(pathOffsets["one"]);

// Add click hadlers to all the circles
var allCircles = document.querySelectorAll("svg circle");
allCircles.forEach(function(circle) {
  circle.addEventListener("click", startShipMovement);
});
```

```css
.route {
  position: relative;
  background-color: linen;
}

.ship {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 1px white;
  background-color: limegreen;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="route">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 1920" xml:space="preserve">
      <path class="cls-1" d="M288.56,7.45c1,1.17,13.77,15.18,14,16.67a8.66,8.66,0,0,1-.65,4.21,117.08,117.08,0,0,1-8.09,18.43c-.36.66-.82,1.39-1.56,1.55a2.71,2.71,0,0,1-1.88-.59L282.72,43a2.5,2.5,0,0,0-4.09.88C270.79,54.35,263,65.09,253.14,73.73c-3,2.61-6.16,5-8.71,8.06-.88,1-1.71,2.38-1.25,3.65a4.35,4.35,0,0,0,1.1,1.49,53.93,53.93,0,0,1,14.12,25.72,4.5,4.5,0,0,1,.12,2.12c-.59,2.2-3.69,2.33-5.41,3.84s-1.75,4.08-1.68,6.34a90,90,0,0,0,1.24,14.12c2,10.3,7.81,19.93,8.07,30.43-2.28,24.14-22.77,45.32-46.87,48.1-2.7.32-5.5.44-8,1.57a20.09,20.09,0,0,0-5,3.7c-32.78,29.91-57.73,67.22-82.35,104.13-2.88,4.32-5.79,8.7-7.48,13.61-2,5.91-2.2,12.26-2.35,18.5-.21,8.75-.38,17.73,2.58,26,3.67,10.22,11.8,18.29,15.91,28.34,4.49,10.93,3.91,23.44,8.47,34.35,1.61,3.85,3.84,7.44,5.16,11.4,2.32,6.94,1.68,14.52,3.28,21.65,2.18,9.7,8.12,20.64,3,29.16a373.16,373.16,0,0,0-36.31,54.7c-4.78,8.8-9.24,17.89-11.68,27.62-2.81,11.19-2.85,22.86-2.88,34.4,0,16.77,0,34,5.78,49.7,2.39,6.51,5.73,12.65,8,19.19,10.3,29.32-1.45,61.63,1,92.61.42,5.43,1.34,11,4,15.71,3.57,6.34,9.92,10.64,16.46,13.82,22.55,10.94,48.91,11,72.34,19.86,12.93,4.92,25.1,12.27,36.75,19.73,5.54-6.69,15.43-8.71,24.11-8.93s17.66.7,25.86-2.17a42.79,42.79,0,0,0,12.9-7.74c15.09-12.46,25-30,33.81-47.45,11.51-22.93,21.95-47.81,20.86-73.43-4.91-2.19-5.89-9.21-10.41-12.13-5.16-3.32-11.87-.21-18,0-7.93.27-15.06-4.5-21.47-9.19a604.83,604.83,0,0,1-70.37-60.38,24.51,24.51,0,0,1-5.05-6.35c-.8-1.66-1.24-3.5-2.27-5-2.1-3.15-6.11-4.31-9.77-5.27-35.8-9.32-70.81-22-104.91-36.35-4.52-7.11-4-16.94-4.71-25.34A85.91,85.91,0,0,0,99,520.19c-1.78-2.94-3.82-6-3.68-9.44a51.33,51.33,0,0,1,1-5.32c1-6.63-3.85-12.53-8-17.74-31.63-39.15-45.62-90.53-74.78-131.56a15.88,15.88,0,0,1-.82-14,14.43,14.43,0,0,1,10.56-8.1c2-.33,4.36-.43,5.38-2.16A5.54,5.54,0,0,0,28.8,328a120,120,0,0,0-3-11.95,21.64,21.64,0,0,0-2-4.93c-1.06-1.75-2.55-3.19-3.73-4.86a33.42,33.42,0,0,1-3.84-8.23c-3.28-9.13-6.58-18.33-8.06-27.92-1-6.17-1.14-12.44-2-18.62A86.93,86.93,0,0,0,.69,231a64.48,64.48,0,0,1,18.11-1.35c-14.94-40.19-3.59-88.94,27-119A156.85,156.85,0,0,1,64.48,95.09C80,83.88,96.75,74.38,113.42,64.9A46.07,46.07,0,0,1,124,60.05c5-1.35,10.31-.95,15.45-1.72C155.85,55.86,168,42.22,182.28,33.7c10.7-6.38,22.85-10,33.83-15.87,7.68-4.14,14.75-9.41,22.7-13s17.61-6.19,25.39-2.24c4.19,2.12,14.08-1.11,15-2.26"; />
      <circle id="one"       cx="295" cy="48"  r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="two"       cx="263" cy="65"  r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="three"     cx="258" cy="103" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="four"      cx="252" cy="135" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="five"      cx="131" cy="305" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="six"       cx="147" cy="502" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="seven"     cx="125" cy="538" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="eight"     cx="110" cy="563" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="nine"      cx="96"  cy="619" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="ten"       cx="110" cy="791" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="eleven"    cx="216" cy="841" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="twelve"    cx="287" cy="846" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="thirteen"  cx="323" cy="817" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="fourteen"  cx="349" cy="766" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="fifteen"   cx="355" cy="720" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="sixteen"   cx="320" cy="705" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="seventeen" cx="265" cy="660" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="eighteen"  cx="102" cy="528" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="nineteen"  cx="96"  cy="498" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="twenty"    cx="22"  cy="306" r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="twentyone" cx="133" cy="59"  r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
      <circle id="twentytwo" cx="230" cy="8"   r="6" stroke="#c7374f" stroke-width="4.5" fill="white" />
    </svg>

    <div class="ship"></div>
  </div>
```